If a reliable person tells you that an item, bearing an otherwise reliable hechsher, is in fact NOT kosher, are you required to investigate the claim?
Suppose I purchase a package of fresh steak bearing a very reliable and respected Hechsher (Kashrut symbol). Before starting up the BBQ, my friend passing by notices the steak and informs me that his son, who works at the slaughterhouse, has become of aware of very questionable practices that call into question the products' kosher status.
Shocked at this claim, I phoned the kosher certifier, and asked them if I can rely on their certification. I was assured that I can absolutely rely on it, and that all Kashrut protocols are strictly followed.
I am torn about what to do. Who do I rely on? My friend is a very refined and scholarly man, as is his son, and have no reason to make this story up. On the other hand, the certifier is insisting there are no issues.
Am I obligated to do my own further investigation? Can I still choose to rely on the Hechsher even though I have plausible claims that it cannot be relied on?
What is the halacha?

Let's simplify the case: two witnesses tell you a piece of meat is kosher and two tell you it isn't. What do you do? What if it's 1vs2? 1vs1?

As asked, can't the answer simply be that the hechsher relies on different halachic opinions from the friend does?

This seems to be a classic case of ask your Rav.

@DoubleAA assume the kashrus standards of both sets of witnesses are exactly the same. What I really getting at is whether there is now an obligation on me to research the matter further before I can eat the meat, or if I can just choose to rely on the hechsher?

The son would have an obligation to report the issue to the kashrus agency for them to investigate.

Someone once asked R. Heinemann about orange juice having bugs in it. He replied "does it have a hechsher? then its good". The guy said but I heard... He replied again "does it have a hechsher? then its good". The guy again started saying but... he replied who knows more, the hechsher or guys hocking. After saying multiple times "does it have a hechsher? then its good", the guy was finally quiet and only then did he give halachic reasoning.

I work in a poultry factory and have observed things that concern me. I spoke to a rav about this and while he didn't address my specific concerns he told me if I didn't feel comfortable eating it then don't buy if it's a financial burden I can rely on the hashgacha. This may not answer your question directly but it's something I can personally relate to. I didn't really feel like my questions were answered satisfactorily so I just avoid eating it personally. No I won't say where since I don't want to speak badly about my place of employment

In the case as you presented it, the hashgacha is an eid echad and your friend is an Eid mipi Eid. In that case you rely on the hechsher.

Why is it an  עד מפי עד, if he himself saw these issues?

@lgshost "Why is it an עד מפי עד, if he himself saw these issues?" In the question you say: "my friend ... informs me that his son, who works at the slaughterhouse, has become of aware of very questionable practices that call into question the products' kosher status." Then, it's not your friend who actually saw these issues, but his son. My question would be: Why isn't the hashgacha an עד מפי עד, as their person you talked to relies on [the testimony of] the mashgiach on site?

@TamirEvan good point. My question really is getting at the situation where I could speak to the son himself and he tells me first hand

I once spoke to a Rav who works for an important kashrus agency and was responsible for kashering a number of factories. He told me that when dealing with big orders of product, such as bags with beans, rice, vegetables, and so on, it is impossible to check each and every item. The production companies usually claim their quality assurance standards and the mashgihim check the production lines. In these cases, the kashrus agencies rely on statistical calculations, which forecast a reasonably small likelihood of infestation or spoilage, given that they randomly select a certain number of items to check out of a big order. The fact that "a reliable person claims" could mean simply that he was unlucky to get the item missed due to small probability of error. Alternatively, even if the friend does not claim anything, the probability always exist that one has to check the food and therefore if s/he makes the claim - more so.
Obviously, one cannot check everything, and it is good to be diligent. Additionally, instead of buying complex processed food items which may have unclaimed and unverifiable ingredients and a kosher sign, it is better and healthier to reduce complexity and prepare food from simpler ingredients, which one can easily verify on one's own.

sounds like good practice and a good anecdote, but doesn't really answer the question

@lgshost added: Alternatively, even if the friend does not claim anything, the probability always exist that one has to check the food and therefore if s/he makes the claim - more so.

"Alternatively ... one has to check the food..." That's all very well in the case of insects or worms in rice or lettuce, but how does that carry over to meat?

"Additionally, instead of buying complex processed food items which may have unclaimed and unverifiable ingredients and a kosher sign ..." The OP's case is about "a package ... bearing a very reliable and respected Hechsher (Kashrut symbol)" that is backed up by the kosher certifier that he spoke to on the phone.

"... it is better and healthier to reduce complexity and prepare food from simpler ingredients, which one can easily verify on one's own." Short of personally supervising the slaughtering, salting etc. (or buying livestock, and doing it oneself), how does one do that for meat?

@TamirEvan you are inventing problems.  We buy raw kosher meat in supermarkets. That's what was meant. Not cooked with unknown ingredients.

@YDJ True, but how does that help with the situation described in the question?

It shows, that there is indeed technically a problem even with items marked as kosher. However, when breaking down to simple items rather than complex preprocessed one can greatly simplify the problem of investigation.

@YDJ "However, when breaking down to simple items rather than complex preprocessed one can greatly simplify the problem of investigation." (1) The question is not about a complex preprocessed item, but a simple package of fresh steak. (2) The question is whether he is required to investigate the matter further, or may he (somewhat blindly) rely on the Hechsher. The alternative of checking the food (like one would with rice or lettuce), is not an available here, and the additional action of reducing complexity and buying a simpler ingredient with a kosher sign, he's already done, and more.

@TamirEvan the shochet is likely to slaughter every bird and every animal correctly by hand and do some investigation when cutting it. The packages that we are dealing with otherwise, due to volume, are checked statistocally and do require investigation prior to cooking. Sometimes infestation can occur with perfectly kosher items such as packages of rice because bugs can be at home/apartment.  Once I rented apartment in Jerusalem which was infested with little ruddy ants.
